# Explanation of Solution: substitution predicate logic

Tags: predicate-logic, substitution

[image]

Midterm coming up later today. Don't understand how in a) the formula doesn't change. I know that x+y is in the scope of Q(x,y,z) but then we're suppose to introduce a new variable and substitute, right?

Please explain please!!

Comment: See answer to the similar post: [substitution-for-bound-variables-in-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307605/substitution-for-bound-variables-in-logic)

Comment: Regarding (c), I agree with you; you have to check the fine details of the formal specifications on your textbook, in order to verify why the "renaming" of $y$ is allowed and that of $x$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The notation $\varphi[t/x]$ denotes that in the formula $\varphi$ all *free occurrences* of the variable $x$ are replaced by $t$, possibly involving renaming to avoid name clashes. Is $x$ free in the $\varphi$ that is mentioned?

Comment: Ah I get it now. For a), all x's are bounded, so there's no free occurrence of x, thus we don't substitute.

Comment: For c) though, I understand that a new variable u is introduced to deal with the y in f(x+y,x), but why didn't we introduce another variable for x?

Comment: nvm, I think it applies to the nearest scope

Answer (score 1):

See Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA112), Academic Press (2nd ed., 2001), page 112, for details.

We need a formal definition of substitution:

> 1. For atomic $α$, $α[t/x]$ is the expression obtained from $α$ by replacing
>      the variable $x$ by $t$.
> 2. *Obvious clauses for the connectives*.
> 3. $(∀y \ α)[t/x] = ∀y \ α$, if $x = y, \ \ \ $ and $ \ \ \ = ∀y \ (α[t/x])$, if $x \ne y$; and the same for $\exists$.

Thus, in case (a) above, $x=y$ in $\varphi := \exists x \ \alpha(x)$ and the result is: $\exists x \ \alpha(x)$.

---

Obviously, we can apply the technique of "alphabetic variant" [see Enderton, [page 126](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA126)] to get a formula $\varphi'$, which differs from $\varphi$ only in the choice of quantified variables, i.e. $\varphi' := \exists w \ \alpha(w)$, such that $\varphi$ and $\varphi'$ are equivalent and $t$ is *substitutable for* [see [page 113](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA113)] $x$ in $\varphi'$.

But in this case the substitution will be: $\varphi' [t/x]$.