# assignment of $f(x_1,x_2)$ (logic)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

i'm trying to understand a concept i can't understand. i don't happen to have any examples, and the explanations are quite bad. from what i understood, i'll try to explain how i tried to solve those questions:

i need to assign the noun $f(x_1,x_2)$ instead of x_1, where it is possible only. if it is not allowed, i need to explain why.

1)$ \forall x_2(R(x_1,x_2) \land \lnot \exists x_1 R(x_1,x_2)) \to \exists x_2(R(x_1,x_3) \land R(x_1,x_2))$

2)$((R(x_1,x_2)\to \forall x_2 P(x_2,x_1)) \land R(x_1,x_2))$

from what i read and understood, the assignment of the noun could only be done iff x_1 is a free variable. which means that it is not possible to do it in 1) because of $\exists x_1$. on the second x_1 doesn't seem to be bound, so it is a free variable and the assignment can be done.

however, i don't know how to actually to the assignment, and would appreciate learning how to do it correctly.

thank you very much for your help,

sorry i could not elaborate more, but i don't understand this concept and the explanations are sufficient nor good in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the post : [substitution for bound variables in first-order logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307605/substitution-for-bound-variables-in-logic).

In a nutshell, the operation of [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)#First-order_logic) in FOL replaces a *free* occurrence of a variable $x$ with a term $t$.

Thus, in 1) you cannot substitute the second (from left) occurrence of $x_1$ with the *term* $f(x_1,x_2)$, because that occurrence of $x_1$ is not *free*.

---

In addition, we have to consider also the concept of *substitutability* (or *free for*) of a term $t$ for a variable $x$ in a formula $\varphi$.

This concept is aimed at avoiding unwanted results obtained with substitution when a variable $y$ occurring in $t$ is "captured" by a quantifier $\forall y$ of $\exists y$ already present in $\varphi$.

Regarding 1), the *term* $f(x_1,x_2)$ is not *substitutable* for the variable $x_1$, because the variable $x_2$ of $f(x_1,x_2)$ will be captured by the quantifiers $∀x_2$ (LHS of $\to$) and $∃x_2$ (RHS of $\to$) respectively.

Regarding 2), the term $f(x_1,x_2)$ is not *substitutable* for $x_1$ in $∀x_2P(x_2,x_1)$.

See the post : [definition of *substitutable* in first-order logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648628/definition-of-substitutable-in-mathematical-logic).

---

---

*Conclusion* : the correct answer to your question depends on the details of the syntactical specifications.

What is the formal definition of "assigning the noun $f(x_1,x_2)$ instead of $x_1$" ?

Comment: when i'll get back home i'll post the definition as its written

Comment: it is defined in my book as following: $φ[t/x]$ is an assignment iff it doesnn't have side effects, meaning that iff no variable in t becomes bounded because of the assignment. does it help a bit?

Comment: for $t_1,..,t_n$ being nouns, then $F(t_1,..,t_n)$ is a noun

Comment: in the other one, is the assignment possible? and if so, how? i think that is is possible because $x_1$ doesn't seem to be bound